# Graph Results shows few throughput charts

Tags: jmeter

I have few HTTP requests gather under single Transaction Controller. generate parent sample is checked.
when i run the test I get around 6 charts for eatch of the parameters - 6 for throughput, 6 for Average and so...
what does it mean?
BTW, if generate parent sample is not checked then I get even more charts - for each of the http samples - this makes sense

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? thx

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements

To have a successful graph generation, you need to uncheck "Generate Parent Sample" otherwise you face the issue you're seeing.

Generate Parent Sample removes information required for the missing graphs, that's why they are blank.

Comment: ok, I understand. so how can I generate chart that sums all of my http requests?

Comment: Just uncheck generate parent sample and ensure you follow other requirements described in the link, you should have all what you need